# Cannot get Gekko to work on moderate size MINLP problem

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I have a problem where it is wanted to maximize an objective function which is a ratio.

Obj: `sum(Ax)/Bx`

For matrices `A` and `B` (of random zeros and ones) that have the same dimension. The problem is unconstrained. So basically I want to find an `x` of zeros and ones that maximizes the given ratio.

Here is a minimum reproducible example of my problem (item 2 below):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

# Number of columns and rows for the given matrices
C = 43
R = 20

# Name columns since I will need to work with dataframes
names = ['n'+str(i) for i in range(C)]
names2 = ['d'+str(i) for i in range(C)]

# Toy example of random distribution of zeros and ones
num = np.random.randint(2, size=(R, C))
den = np.random.randint(2, size=(R, C))
df_num = pd.DataFrame(columns=names, data=num)
df_den = pd.DataFrame(columns=names2, data=den)

# Start Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,(df_num.shape[1]),lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
for i in x:
    i.value = np.random.randint(2, size=1)[0]
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 1']
ival1 = m.Intermediate(df_num.mul(x).sum(1).sum())
ival2 = m.Intermediate(df_den.mul(x).sum(1).sum())
m.Obj(-np.divide(ival1, ival2))
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
m.solve(disp=True)
```

I tried following the instructions given [here](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/IntegerBinaryVariables) and [here](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) and some other places, so I used the `minlp_as_nlp 1` option to relax the integer restriction and also used intermediate variables to see if it helps, however, I cannot get the model to work.

Basically, the following 2 issues happen:

**1. No solution is found (x is all zeros)**

That's when I have a very small problem (like the one above, but with 42 columns or less, however, my actual problem ranges from 10k x 5e2 to 7e6 x 5e2). I would expect `x` to have the final values found, but it is all zeros. This is what APM prints out:

```sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           42
   Intermediates:            2
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            3
   Residuals    :            1
 
 Number of state variables:             42
 Number of total equations: -            0
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             42
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.04 NLPi:   18 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -2.17E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   4.780000000027940E-002 sec
 Objective      :   -2.16666666666667     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

**2. Runtime error**

When I increase the number of columns to 43 (as above or more), I get the following error (edited to fit space):

```sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 @error: Max Equation Length
 Error with line number:           48
 i28=(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((0)*(int_v1))
 +((0)*(int_v2)))+((0)*(int_v3)))+((1)*(int_v4)))+((1)*(int_v5)))+((1)*(int_v6))
 )+((0)*(int_v7)))+((1)*(int_v8)))+((0)*(int_v9)))+((1)*(int_v10)))+((0)*(int_v1
.
.
.
_v31)))+((0)*(int_v32)))+((0)*(int_v33)))+((1)*(int_v34)))+((1)*(int_v35)))+((1
 )*(int_v36)))+((1)*(int_v37)))+((0)*(int_v38)))+((0)*(int_v39)))+((0)*(int_v40)
 ))+((0)*(int_v41)))+((0)*(int_v42)))+((1)*(int_v43))))
 
 APM model error: string >       15000  characters
 Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations
 
 The may also be due to only using newline character CR
   instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux) 
 To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters
 
 STOPPING...
 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-5885f6e9b4ca> in <module>
      6 m.Obj(-np.divide(ival1, ival2))
      7 m.options.SOLVER = 1
----> 8 m.solve(disp=True)

/anaconda_env/personal/rafaeldasilv/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py in solve(self, disp, debug, GUI, **kwargs)
   2128                 print("Error:", errs)
   2129             if (debug >= 1) and record_error:
-> 2130                 raise Exception(apm_error)
   2131 
   2132         else: #solve on APM server

Exception: @error: Max Equation Length
 Error with line number:           48
 i28=(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((0)*(int_v1))
 +((0)*(int_v2)))+((0)*(int_v3)))+((1)*(int_v4)))+((1)*(int_v5)))+((1)*(int_v6))
 )+((0)*(int_v7)))+((1)*(int_v8)))+((0)*(int_v9)))+((1)*(int_v10)))+((0)*(int_v1
 1)))+((1)*(int_v12)))+((1)*(int_v13)))+((0)*(int_v14)))+((1)*(int_v15)))+((1)*(
.
.
.
 )+((1)*(int_v27)))+((0)*(int_v28)))+((1)*(int_v29)))+((0)*(int_v30)))+((0)*(int
 _v31)))+((0)*(int_v32)))+((0)*(int_v33)))+((1)*(int_v34)))+((1)*(int_v35)))+((1
 )*(int_v36)))+((1)*(int_v37)))+((0)*(int_v38)))+((0)*(int_v39)))+((0)*(int_v40)
 ))+((0)*(int_v41)))+((0)*(int_v42)))+((1)*(int_v43))))
 
 APM model error: string >       `15000`  characters
 Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations
 
 The may also be due to only using newline character CR
   instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux) 
 To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters
 
 STOPPING...
```

Would anyone have any guess of what I could be missing here or even if this is the right approach? Thank you!

**EDIT: Solution after running suggested code change (R=400, C=76):**

```sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :          802
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :        61678
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :        62402
   Equations    :        60801
   Residuals    :        60801
 
 Number of state variables:          61678
 Number of total equations: -        61602
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :             76
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      1.60 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj: -1.00E+00 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   0.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:  -1.00E+00 Gap:   1.00E+00
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.44 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  0.00E+00 Gap:  1.00E+00
Iter:     3 I:  0 Tm:      1.37 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    4 Obj: -1.00E+00 Gap:  1.00E+00
--Integer Solution:  -1.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:  -1.00E+00 Gap:   2.82E-06
Iter:     4 I:  0 Tm:      0.45 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    4 Obj: -1.00E+00 Gap:  2.82E-06
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    4.02930000000015      sec
 Objective      :  -0.999995215333898     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 

Runtime: 1568.80s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Gekko summation to avoid a long symbolic expression.

```py
m.Maximize(m.sum(Ax)/m.sum(Bx))
```

No solution is found because the denominator goes to zero, creating an objective of infinity. This can be avoided by adding a small constant to the denominator such as:

```py
m.Maximize(m.sum(Ax)/(m.sum(Bx)+1e-3))
```

The current version without `m.sum()` produces an objective function expression that is over 15,000 characters long.

I also switched to `A@x` and `B@x` to simplify the matrix multiplication expressions but your original Pandas expressions also work.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

# Number of columns and rows for the given matrices
C = 43
R = 20

# Name columns since I will need to work with dataframes
names = ['n'+str(i) for i in range(C)]
names2 = ['d'+str(i) for i in range(C)]

# Toy example of random distribution of zeros and ones
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(R, C))
B = np.random.randint(2, size=(R, C))

# Start Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Array(m.Var,C,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
for i in x:
    i.value = np.random.randint(2, size=1)[0]
m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 1']

# Calculate Ax and Bx
Ax = A@x
Bx = B@x

# Maximize ratio
m.Maximize(m.sum(Ax)/(m.sum(Bx)+1e-3))

# Solve
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # APOPT solver
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Solution:

```
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
   30 -2.19956E+00  1.30104E-18
   31 -2.19956E+00  6.93889E-18
   32 -2.19956E+00  6.93889E-18
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.13 sec
 Objective      :  -2.1995600879824035
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit: Alternative Matrix Multiplication**

Use Gekko summations for the matrix multiplication if there are much larger matrices.

```py
# Calculate Ax and Bx
#Ax = A@x
#Bx = B@x
Ax = [m.sum([A[i,j]*x[j] for j in range(C)]) for i in range(R)]
Bx = [m.sum([A[i,j]*x[j] for j in range(C)]) for i in range(R)]
```

This solves successfully with `C=43` and `R=20` but would also be applicable to much larger matrices.

Comment: Thanks @johnh It looks confusing to me the why and when using sum since I thought the dot product operation would do it. Also my take from the [documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=sum#pre-built-objects) is that the use of sum is optional in most cases. I had run your code and still get the error 2. I noticed my APM monitor is 0.9.2 and your APOPT is 1.0 (are they related?), my gekko version is 0.2.8, I tried to upgrade it but it seems to be up to date. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: It may just be the random numbers that are chosen - those aren't necessarily deterministic for the script. Maybe try using `A` and `B` matrices that are fixed or else make the randomizer deterministic with a fixed seed value?

Comment: I tried around 100 times to see if the random numbers would be the issue, but that didn't help. But even with that, shouldn't the library find a solution? I think I can't understand why the sparsity in the matrix would influence the error.

Comment: Could you try it with the new matrix multiplication form?

Comment: Yes that worked with 43 columns, and 20 rows. I also tried with 100 columns and 20 rows and it worked with no problems. I reduced the size of my original problem to 11k rows by 75 columns, it's currently running, I will keep you posted, thanks John. Is there any place where I can find such functionalities of m.sum?

Comment: There is a little additional information in the documentation: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=m.sum#pre-built-objects  You can also see the underlying model it constructs by opening gk_model0.apm in the run folder `m.path` or by opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()`.

Comment: My first attempt to run the full problem took about 3 days and I interrupted it accidentally. I have run a couple of smaller problems to estimate the runtime of the full problem (the runtime is basically a geometric sequence, which for each doubling of the number of rows, the runtime increases by 4x) So for my original problem the answer would come after about 18 days.